# Creating a list event receiver with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I cannot find the create list event receiver wizard in VS2013 - it was there in VS2010.  I want to be able to add an event receiver (in C# - item_added) to an already existing list.

In VS 2010 it was easy you just ran the create list event receiver wizard.  In VS2013 I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Visual Studio 2013 and create an Empty SharePoint Project.

[image]

- Enter site URL and select Deploy as a farm solution and click Finish.
  [image]
- Open Solution Explorer and add a new item.
  [image]
- Select event receiver and enter the title of the event receiver. Click the Add button.
  [image]
- Select List Item Events in type of event receiver and select the Document Library option from the event source. Then select an events as in the following and click Finish.
  [image]
- The following screen will appear. Here I'm trying to update a SharePoint list based on file changes happening to a separate SharePoint Document Library.

Basically, the list will act like a document log. So we need to create the library and a list.

Here, I have created the EmployeeDocuments library to add and maintain documents and also created an EmployeeDocumentLog list to log the changes happening to the library.
[image]

Reference [Article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 3):

- Open Visual Studio 2013
- Create new  project from file > New > New Project
- Select SharePoint 2013 - Empty Project.

[image]

- Right click on your Project > Add > Add new item > you should now get Event Receiver.

[image]

- Now the SharePoint Customization wizard should be shown.

[image]

**Note :**

To apply it Event Receiver to already custom list

- At SharePoint Customization wizard > What Item Should be the event source.
- Select the list Content Type (EX: if it's custom list select Custom list) >
- Then select the event required > click finish.
- Now open `Element.xml` at solution explorer.
- Change  `<Receivers ListTemplateId="100" >` To  `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/yourlist">`