# Raise event when someone add item to list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

As a newbie in sharepoint I'm trying to learn some stuff.

I have list created in EventReceiver (FeatureActivated method). I would like to raise an event when someone will try edit or add new item to list. Where can I find a sample of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding the below two events in your current solution:

- **ItemAddedded:** to fire an event when a new item added to your list.
- **ItemUpdated:** to fire an event when an item updated.

---

**To add a new Event function to the current Event Receiver Solution, try to do the following:**

- Open Visual Studio.
- Open Event Receiver Solution.
- Right click on the **Event Receiver Name** > select `Properties`.

[image]

- Set `Handle ItemAddedded`, `Handle ItemUpdated` to **TRUE**.
- Go back to the code, The event functions should be now added as shown below.

  ```
  public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

       base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }
  ```

---

For more details, check [Creating a list event receiver with Visual Studio 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200709/creating-a-list-event-receiver-with-visual-studio-2013/200804#200804)